# How to correct this construction "despite still weak results"? I want to fix the word 'still'

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence correct, and if not, how would you correct it?
"Sales are better despite **still weak** margins"

Answer (score 1):

It isn't incorrect but "continuing" feels more natural and indicates an unchanging trend over time.

> Sales are better despite continuing weak margins.

It's a little different to "still" in that it connotes more strongly a future trend as well.

Comment: I think this is the closest I can get. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The wording is awkward, but can be improved by using *to be* to attach the adjective *weak* to *margins*:

> Sales are better despite margins **still being weak**.

I do question the logic of the sentence, though - I would have thought it was more logical to say:

> Margins are still weak despite better/improved/improving sales.

Though this obviously depends on what margins you're talking about - gross or effective net.

Answer (score 0):

The word **Still** can be used to make a comparison stronger.
But in that case it is usually used as

> The number of people killed in the explosion is likely to rise still higher.
>   The company is hoping to extend its market still further.

So your sentence may be written as

> Sales are better despite still weaker margins.